# Conceptual question about cavity inside a sphere of uniform charge

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-fields

I understand why the E-Field isn't $0$ in the cavity (denoted by the white circle) and the red area denoting the uniform charge distribution. This is because of the Flux through the spherical cavity essentially not being zero, therefore $\nabla \cdot E \neq 0$ or equivalently $\oint_A\vec{E} \cdot\vec{da} \neq 0 $. However, then by this logic, shouldn't this mean that we have a charge enclosed in the cavity, which cannot be the case since it's a vacuum? My logic is that since $\oint_A\vec{E} \cdot\vec{da} = Q_{enc}/\epsilon_{0} \neq 0$ this then means there is a charge enclosed in the sphere.

I know that we can "simulate" the boundary conditions by placing a sphere of -ve charge in place of the cavity. However, when one considers the problem itself, there is no charge inside the cavity, so does $\oint_A\vec{E} \cdot\vec{da} = Q_{enc}/\epsilon_{0}$ not hold here?

If anyone could shed light and help me understand this it would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see my logical flaw. $∮E⃗ ⋅da=0$, however this does not mean that there is no E-Field passing through, right? It only means that the FLUX is $0$. So Gauss' Law holds, but we must be careful. I'll leave this up nonetheless, in case anyone comes against the same question again.

Comment: Yes, you found it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the asymmetry of this particular charge distribution around the hollowed out spherical cavity there is going to be an electric field everywhere inside the cavity.